# The variation of Calderon reproducing formula

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, harmonic-analysis

I'm reading the book 'Classical and multilinear harmonic analysis, Muscalu'. I fail to understand the page 261. Actually, I doubt that the proof is right.

Let $f \in BMO(\mathbb{R^d}$) have compact surpport and mean zero. Let $\phi \in S$ be radial, $supp(\phi) \subset B(0,1) $, $\int \hat{\phi}(t\xi)^2\frac{dt}{t}=1$. The author says that

> The Calderon reproduing formula now becomes the following statement:
>   $$f(x)=\int_0^\infty (\phi_t * \phi_t * f)(x)\frac{dt}{t}$$

I know that the above identity holds if $f \in L^2$. But we just assumed that $f \in L^1 \cap BMO$ and $f$ has compact support.

Comment: Every BMO function is in $L^p_{loc}$, meaning on compact sets every BMO function has finite $L^p$ norm. Since $f$ is compact and BMO, it is actually in all $L^p$, particularly $L^2$. Unless I'm missing your point.

Comment: @CameronWilliams How to prove that every BMO function is in $L^p_{loc}$? I haven't seen that statement.

Comment: Oh, John-Nirenberg inequality implies that. Thanks!

Comment: You can find the statement in *Modern Approaches to the Invariant Subspace Problem* but I'm not sure how one would go about proving it. My hunch would be that since BMO functions are naturally defined in terms of local behavior and there is a nesting of $L^p$ spaces, i.e. if $q \le p$, then $L^p \subseteq L^q$ on finite measure spaces, you should be able to argue it. Particularly, you could probably argue that they are locally $L^p$ for $p\ge 1$ by such an argument (since they are locally integrable), then by using some neat interpolation trick prove it for all $L^p$ ($0 < p$).

Comment: Thank you. How kind of you!